# Is there a way to change the default eclipse toolbar icons built into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, icons, toolbar, built-in

I am talking about the tiny icons on the toolbar. 
There doesn't seem to be any questions like this on the web, they all refer to android or a custom application as opposed to the icons bundled with eclipse.

I want to know if anyone has tried this or can tell me that its not worth my time because it is a lot of work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. The standard icons are declared using the `org.eclipse.ui.commandImages` extension point in the `org.eclipse.ui` plugin and reference icons in that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Darkest Dark Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme). Also its dev style preview (for more themes). It can change icons as well as have an icon designer integrated in it.