# How to change Eclipse's icons?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, ide, icons

Haven't found a single question here. Is it possible to somehow change Icon Pack?

I'm speaking about these icons:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmjFl.png

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change the default eclipse toolbar icons built into eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541506/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-eclipse-toolbar-icons-built-into-eclipse)

Comment: Actually yes. But I think it was almost half-year ago, so maybe something changed. :C

Comment: No, nothing has changed

Comment: Don't ask duplicate questions! If you find that an existing question hasn't received enough attention, make sure that it is well written (improve it if needed), and if there is still no answer, place a bounty on it. (You need to earn some reputation first though.)

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541506/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-eclipse-toolbar-icons-built-into-eclipse